# WebRTC: use of getStats()

Tags: javascript, webrtc, bandwidth, mediastream

I'm trying to get stats of a webRTC app to measure audio/video streaming bandwidth.
I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069419/webrtc-getstat-api-set-up) and I found it very useful; however, when I try to use it I get

```
TypeError: Not enough arguments to RTCPeerConnection.getStats.
```

I think that is because of in 2016 something in webRTC is changed and now there are mediaStreamTracks; however I built the project without mediaStreamTracks and I don't know how to change this function to get it to work.

Do you have any ideas? 
Thanks for your support!

**UPDATE:**

My call is

```
peer.pc.onaddstream = function(event) {
      peer.remoteVideoEl.setAttribute("id", event.stream.id);
      attachMediaStream(peer.remoteVideoEl, event.stream);
      remoteVideosContainer.appendChild(peer.remoteVideoEl);
      getStats(peer.pc);
};
```

and getStats() is identical to this [link](http://muaz-khan.blogspot.it/2014/05/webrtc-tips-tricks.html) at chapter n.7.

Comment: Post some code. Especially your call of `getStats()`

Comment: `getStats()` needs a `mediaStreamTrack` as parameter, if i recall.

Comment: Updated question! P.s: what if I call `peer.getStats(null, function(...) )` ?

Comment: That should. The track is only a filter, and can be left out with `null`.

Comment: I would close this as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800010/can-someone-comprehensively-explain-the-webrtc-stats-api/29840886), except you seem to want it to work in Chrome specifically, is that right?

Comment: I think it would be ok, could you please just add tags "bandwidth" and "mediastream", or "statistics" to the original question? I'm new and I can't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

been sometime since I used WebRTC, problem then was, chrome and firefox implemented it differently( believe they still do it differently)

Firefox:

webrtc stats tab is `about:webrtc`

```
peerConnection.getStats(null).then(function(stats){...  // returns a promise
```

Chrome:

webrtc stats tab is `chrome://webrtc-internals/`

```
peerConnection.getStats(function(stats){ // pass a callback function
```

one way to circumvent these cross browser issues is using [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter)

Comment: Yes Firefox implements it to [spec](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-stats), Chrome does not. See [this question](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/issues/5). - Yes, adapter.js helps on calling convention, but note it does not rename Chrome-specific stats keys [yet](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/issues/5).